# unable to convert string to float in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to calculate the difference of sales and expenses from the database values that I have returned. But when I use `a - b` it throws the below error. Although I'm converting the  double it still gives the error:

```
cannot implicitly convert type string to double
```

This is my code:

```
double a = Double.Parse(reader["sales"].ToString().Trim());
double b  = Double.Parse(reader["expenses"].ToString().Trim());

Label11.Text = a - b;
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: When you debug, are `a` and `b` properly doubles? Have you tried doing `Label11.Text = (a-b).ToString();`?

Comment: both are returning double but adding that worked perfectly.. thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `Text` is of type `string` and the values obviously aren't (and therefore neither is the resulting value) of that type:

```
Label11.Text = (a - b).ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of: `Label11.Text = a - b;`
use `Label11.Text = (a - b).ToString();`

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're sure that you're always going to have valid `double` values in the string then you might want to use `TryParse` instead in order to ensure no exceptions are thrown.

```
double a;
double b;

if (double.TryParse(reader["sales"].ToString().Trim(), out a))  
if (double.TryParse(reader["expenses"].ToString().Trim(), out b))        
    Label11.Text = (a - b).ToString(); //only called if both doubles were parsed
```